# Find best nonlinear equation for data

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, nonlinear

I have the following data:

https://pastebin.com/APjy2G3Q

which plotted with `ListLinePlot[data]` looks like:

[image]

Does anybody know what will be the best non-linear equation to fit this kind of data using `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: Would it really be useful to you if someone here provided a, most likely, very complicated and arbitrary function that somehow fits these data? What would you do with that function, and how could you possibly trust it to give meaningful results? Surely the data must _mean_ something, and that meaning should guide what kind of function(s) that can be considered for the fit.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thank you for your comment. Yes, it would be very useful if someone would provide the function that fits the data. This data in particular comes from a deconvolution of other peaks it the function that describes it would be very useful to me to be able to predict or at least estimate another transition (in a thermogram) that may occur.

Comment: While I think an answer to your question would be very useful to you and provide an interesting problem to solve for someone, I don't see that it would be helpful to have on this forum.  Also, it's not really about *Mathematica*.  Hence, I have voted to close the question.

Comment: @JimB. Okay. Yes, you are right. I was just hoping that perhaps someone here may know a possible equation that would describe this or similar kind of data as there are several people here (including you) very good at this.

Comment: Take a look at `ListLogPlot[data]` and the answer will be crystal clear.  Yes, with that things are linear until they aren't.  Not much good for predicting a transition.  Listen to @MariusLadegårdMeyer.

Comment: @John to illustrate my point, since you don't tell us anything that could guide us in choosing appropriate models for the data, I could propose using a Fourier series. If you shift your data so that the first x-value is zero (`shiftedData = 
  Table[{data[[i, 1]] - data[[1, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}, {i, 
    Length[data]}];`) and then do `model = a[0]/2 + 
   Sum[a[n] Cos[2 Pi n x/xMax] + b[n] Sin[2 Pi n x/xMax], {n, 1, 
     100}];` followed by `ans = NonlinearModelFit[shiftedData, model, 
  Join[a /@ Range[0, 100], b /@ Range[1, 100]], x]`, that gives you.... something.

Comment: _continued_. It can even look "quite good" if you bump the upper limit of `n` from 100 to, I don't know, 500. Will it be a useful model? I really hope no one would think so.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and patience @MariusLadegårdMeyer and MarcoB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model = If[74.0202` < x <= 91.1583, a*x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, 0];
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d}, x]
Show[
 Plot[model /. fit, {x, 70, 100}, PlotStyle -> Thick],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
]
```

[image: fit plot]

Comment: flinty thank you very much for your answer and help ! I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 4):

`LogPlot` shows that your data could be exponential. On the other hand, it can also be a cubic function as flinty shows. Thus, *any interpretation of the data has not much sense without knowing the appropriate model*.

```
g[y_, z_] := Exp[y/z] UnitStep[-y]
cleandata = data[[3 ;;]];
p1 = First[cleandata];
p2 = Last[Cases[cleandata, {x_, y_} /; y > 0]];
p3 = Last[cleandata];

k = (p2[[1]] - p1[[1]])/(Log[p2[[2]]] - Log[p1[[2]]])
a = p2[[1]]
b = p2[[2]]
g1 = LogPlot[b g[x - a, k], {x, p1[[1]], p3[[1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red];
g0 = ListLogPlot[cleandata];
Show[g0, g1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I really appreciate it (+1)